# Looking for a book series where a man is abducted by aliens and cloned

Tags: story-identification, clones

In the books, he eventually works with his clones and clones of his girlfriend to defeat the aliens.  At the end of the series, I think there are four sets of clones.  Each of the main character's clones is matched to a version of his girlfriend's clones except for one.  That clone finds an old girlfriend and ends up with her.  Each of the clones end up having their own personality.  Any help finding this series would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When did you read this? In what language? Was it new at the time? Do you remember anything else about it?

Comment: I bought the first book at a grocery store in Fort Wayne, Indiana.  It was one of those books they have on the racks for impulse buys.  It would probably have been between 1996 and 2001 as my best guess and would also have been a new book at the time.  The language was English.

The book took place off of Earth.  The main character was abducted to use for experiments.  The aliens would clone him, use his clone until it died, then clone him again.  Eventually he escaped with three of his clones, defeated the aliens, and made it back to Earth.

Comment: @SPQRGuyMontag Ideally you add this information to the post

Comment: The plot is similar to C. J. Cherryh's *Voyager in Night*, but it's a single novel, not a series.